# Owl-Carousel, scroll two items at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I am working on a slider with Owl-Carousel 2 (beta), but there is a lot that doesn't work well.
I want the owlCarousel to work like this:

It should scroll 2 items at a time, showing 2 items at a time.
So: [0,1] *slide* [2,3] *slide* [4,5]

On mobile, it should show one picture and scroll by 1 picture at a time.

```
owl = $('.owl-carousel')
  owl.owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    loop: false,
    margin: 20,
    items: 2,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
        navigation: true,
        nav: true
      },
      640: {
        items: 2,
        navigation: true,
        nav: true
      }
    },
    scrollPerPage: true,
    navigation: true
  }).css("z-index", 0)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`slideBy`](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-options.html#slideby) option.

```
owl = $('.owl-carousel')
  owl.owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    loop: false,
    margin: 20,
    items: 2,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
        navigation: true,
        nav: true,
        slideBy: 1 // <!-- HERE
      },
      640: {
        items: 2,
        navigation: true,
        nav: true,
        slideBy: 2 // <!-- HERE
      }
    },
    scrollPerPage: true,
    navigation: true
  }).css("z-index", 0)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it is still scrolling one image at a time.

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/y1p0t5dk/ Are you using a recent version of the beta?

Comment: Also, I don't think `center: true,` makes sense if displaying two items

Comment: After removing `center: true, loop; false` it did work :D
Thank you, Sexy Turnip.