# slideBy owlCarousel does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I need to have it so that on click of the navigation, the owl carousel slides by 6 instead of 1. The relevant configuration below:

```
$(function() {
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    // mobile
    nav: false,
    navText: '',
    items: 2,
    responsiveClass:true,
    // desktop
    responsive:{
        980:{
            items:6,
            nav: true,
            navText: '',
            slideBy: 6
        }
    }
  });
});
```

I found out about [slideBy](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html#slideby) from:

[Slide 2 items in OWL Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045951/slide-2-items-in-owl-carousel)

[Owl-Carousel, scroll two items at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843347/owl-carousel-scroll-two-items-at-a-time)

[owl carousel slide n by n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810870/owl-carousel-slide-n-by-n)

But in my instance it does not work. What configurations do I need to add/remove to get this working?

Comment: it should be working just fine. Do you have any errors or which version you are using?

Comment: @Manjunath I needed to change the OC version and now it's fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change from 2.2.1 to 2.3.4 to access this feature.